# How many endings can I get in Ib?

Tags: ib

I have played this game a lot, and it seems that I have gotten 3 endings already.

> One where Ib is all alone, one where everything turns to normal, but Gary dies. Also, the third ending was that Mary turned into my sister, and we went back with Ib's parents, like it was normal. I am not sure, but is there a bonus ending?? Or another one that I missed??

Answer (score 1):

In the game there are seven possible endings. Each ending has different variations and each variation has different outcomes which impact MORE different characters. There are a total of 39 different possible endings. All the endings and their possibilities are [here](http://ibgame.wikia.com/wiki/Endings).

---

You described the 2 most common endings and you can reach them a multitude of different ways all of which can be found on the website.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually nine main endings that are commonly used, but there are variations. For example, the Ib all alone ending has three variations.

The worst main ending is Painting's Demise, where Mary escapes while Ib and Garry eventually die in the gallery. Mary is told that her heart is fabricated and she cannot leave.

The second worst is Welcome to the World of Guertena. Mary leads Ib and Garry to a room, where the paintings pluck their roses. They then die to the real world, and Mary traps them forever to "play" with her.

The best ending is Promise of Reunion, where Ib lends Garry her handkerchief when he cuts his hand. However you can only do this if you have enough bond points with Garry. If not, you do not get the choice. They then return to the painting in which they should jump through. At that moment Ib's fake mother comes in. If you follow Ib's "mother", you get Ib all alone. If you follow Garry, you get Promise of Reunion.

Based on personal opinions, Forgotten Portrait is the saddest ending. Mary plucks Garry's rose and kills him, but when you return to the real world, there is a portrait of Garry. Then Ib goes home and nothing happens.

The endings you got were Ib all alone, Together Forever, and I think Forgotten Portrait.

Together Forever is where Mary becomes Ib's "sister" 
The reason she could escape the gallery is because in a different ending, when you go burn down her portrait, Mary's diary reads that she must be able to take the place of someone already existing in the real world.

1.Painting's Demise
2.Welcome to the World of Guertana
3.Ib all alone (version 1)
4.Ib all alone (version 2)
5.Ib all alone (version 3)
6.Forgotten Portrait
7.Together Forever
8.Promise of Reunion

It is agreed that there are different variations and they influence even MORE endings.