# How many endings are in the Ib remake?

Tags: ib

The original 2012 version of Ib had [7 different endings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/133552/181240). Have the endings been changed at all for the [2022 remake](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1901370/Ib/)? Have any new endings been added?

Comment: @Skye-AT My apologies. I sometimes like to wait a few days before accepting an answer to see if a more detailed answer is provided. I sometimes forget to go back and accept an answer.

Comment: No worries, people forget thousand things every day, I guess that was just one thing that you've forgot - Sorry if it offended you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though there is some additional(and some deleted) content to the game, no ending was added.

[Source](https://www.chaptercheats.com/cheat/switch/574979/Ib/hint/179092/)